# SQL Update with Case/IFs

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have 8 bit columns, A1,A2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4. All 8 are completely independent and its based on these that another field should be populated.

I want to update this other field with the text A, B or AB depending on which of any of the 8 columns are set to 1.

Here are a couple of examples; 
 - all 8 fields are set to 1 then populate with AB,
 - if A3 and B1 are set to 1 then populate with AB,
 - if A1 and A3 are set to 1 then populate with A,
 - if B4 and B2 are set to 1 then populate with B.

So for any combination of A1 through B4 the field should be set

Below is the what I have tried but it is incomplete but will give an idea;

**UPDATE**

Correct answer from adrianm

```
UPDATE m
SET ref = ASet + BSet 
FROM contactMaster m
inner join contact c on 
m.contactid = c.contactid
 CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT CASE WHEN (c.A1 | c.A2 | c.A3 | c.A4) = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END AS ASet
           ,CASE WHEN (c.B1 | c.B2 | c.B3 | c.B4) = 1 THEN 'D' ELSE '' END AS BSet
 ) AS CA1 
where ref is null
```

Comment: Your requirement isn't really clear. You didn't mention if only two columns can only be set to '1' at the same time or multiple is be allowed.

Comment: Multiple is allowed. All 8 are completely independent and its based on these that the other field should be populated.

Comment: Please take your time to edit your question and add quite a lot more details. Tell us what your exact requirements are, what you've tried (include code) and why you got stuck on those solutions, help us repro the situation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE ContactMaster
    SET ref = ASet + BSet 
FROM ContactMaster
     INNER JOIN Contact
          ON ContactMaster.ContactId = Contact.ContactId
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT CASE WHEN (Contact.A1 | Contact.A2 | Contact.A3 | Contact.A4) = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END AS ASet
               ,CASE WHEN (Contact.B1 | Contact.B2 | Contact.B3 | Contact.B4) = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END AS BSet
     ) AS CA1 
WHERE ContactMaster.ref IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (Select Count(*) from table where A1=1 AND A2 =1 AND a3 =1 AND a4 =1 AND b1 =1 AND b2 =1 AND b3 =1 AND b4=1 )>0
    BEGIN

    UPDATE MyTable 
    SET ColumnValue ='AB' 
    where A1=1 AND A2 =1 AND a3 =1 AND a4 =1 AND b1 =1 AND b2 =1 AND b3 =1 AND b4=1
    END

   ELSE IF (Select Count(*) from table where A1 =1 and A3 =1 )>0

    BEGIN
     Update MyTable set columnValue ='A'
     where A1 =1 and A3 =1
    END
```